# PHP Check slave status without mysql_connect timeout issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web-app that has a master mysql db and four slave dbs.  I want to handle all (or almost all) read-only (SELECT) queries from the slaves.  Our load-balancer sends the user to one of the slave machines automatically, since they are also running Apache/PHP and serving webpages.  I am using an include file to setup the connection to the databases, such as:

```
//for master server (i.e. - UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements)
$Host = "10.0.0.x";
$User = "xx";
$Password = "xx";
$Link = mysql_connect( $Host, $User, $Password );
if( !$Link ) )
{
   die( "Master database is currently unavailable.  Please try again later." );
}

//this connection can be used for READ-ONLY (i.e. - SELECT statements) on the localhost
$Host_Local = "localhost";
$User_Local = "xx";
$Password_Local = "xx";
$Link_Local = mysql_connect( $Host_Local, $User_Local, $Password_Local );

//fail back to master if slave db is down
if( !$Link_Local ) )
{
   $Link_Local = mysql_connect( $Host, $User, $Password );
}
```

I then use $Link for all update queries and $Link_Local as the connection for SELECT statements.  Everything works fine until the slave server database goes down.  If the local db is down, the $Link_Local = mysql_connect() call takes at least 30 seconds before it gives up on trying to connect to the localhost and returns back to the script.  This causes a huge backlog of page serves and basically shuts down the system (due to the extremely slow response time).

Does anyone know of a better way to handle connections to slave servers via PHP?  Or, is there some kind of timeout function that could be used to stop the mysql_connect call after 2-3 seconds?

Thanks for the help.  I searched the other mysql_connect threads, but didn't see any that addressed this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the [MySQL] section of your php.ini, set this value:

```
; Maximum time (in secondes) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
mysql.connect_timeout = 1
```

If you have 4 db slaves, then you should have a pretty decent network that can respond to a db request in under 1 second. Trust your server build.

Then fix your slaves going down!! That is a PROBLEM!!

Finally, not every page request should need a link to the master DB. You should try putting a connection manager class in place that will decide based on the query type which database to use. That will lower the number of connections to your master DB as well.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the info.  I will look into the connector class.  I am still learning the OO side of PHP, so getting a class to work might be an issue!  Your response was perfect for my current situation though.

Comment: I tried to give you an upvote, but the system says I have to have at least 15 reputation points!  Sorry!